# Refresh Content Without Changing Page

Tags: xml, ajax, xslt

I am creating a small commercial website where I want only the content to change, and the header/footer to stay. My goal is to change the content without changing the URL.

I originally was planning to use AJAX but I realized that each page has a different layout so I wasn't sure how to accompany this. If I were to use AJAX, I would store all the data in XML. In that case, would I have to create a new XSLT for each page? Is there a better solution then this?

Comment: Why are you planning to use XML and XSLT ?

Comment: The only storage solutions for AJAX I am aware of are using a database, and XML. As this site is only several pages in size, I felt it was overkill to use a database.

Comment: Today most AJAX uses json as the medium, even if originally the name AJAX came from XML (and the internal used object is still XmlHttpRequest). If you don't have serious reasons to use XML, don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 main ways :

**1)** you can include html in all your pages with a common js file. This is coherent with your initial choice.

Your fonction could be like this (supposing you use jquery, which I recommend) :

```
// that's in the js file
function addHeaderAndFooter() {   
    var html = '<div id=myheader>header stuff</div>';
    $(html).prependTo('body');
}
```

You then would call it like this :

```
// that's in each html file
$(window).load(function(){
    addHeaderAndFooter(); // that's your function defined in your common js
});
```

**2)** a server side generation system : With PHP for example it's easy to include constant elements in all your pages. Fact is that very few commercial sites can really avoid the use of server side generation.

Usage of XML and XSLT is possible but not so frequent today as it is heavy and not human friendly.

It's hard to say without more requirements if you should use solution 1 or 2, but for somebody not really versed in hardcore developpement and supposing your site will have more that 3 o 4 pages, I'd recommend to use something like PHP : it's more classical.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more on your first point? Do you mean using javascript to control which content code (which is stored in the js file) gets display by using something such as `getElementById('content').innerHTML=locationPage`?

Comment: From my understanding of method 1, it seems that that I would go to a new URL when I navigate through the website. I was trying to achieve the effect where I do not have to go to a new URL when navigating through my site. Did I mid-understand your explanation?

Comment: Both solutions change the URL. And I really recommend to do it for a commercial web site : it's harder, without changes in URL, to let users bookmark specific pages/articles and to let Google completely index your site.

Comment: My client insisted that he did not want the URL to change. The reason is because there is some information in the header/footer that contains user selection, and needs to remain consistent throughout the site. Is there any solution where the URL does not change? Would using AJAX/JSON still be my best bet?

Comment: If you put the same header and footer everywhere, the URL change isn't a problem.

Comment: How would I save the user selection in the header/footer and pass it to the next page? Would this be possible to handle on the client side?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11157/discussion-between-dystroy-and-user1277607)